# Final value theorem for Laplace transform of a nonnegative random variable

Tags: probability, analysis

Laplace (or Fourier) transforms allow in particular to obtain results in the original "time" domain from the behavior in the "frequency" domain. For instance, if $\hat{f}(s)=\int_0^{+\infty} \! dt \, e^{-s t} f(t)$ is the usual (one-sided) Laplace transform of a function $f$ (assuming everything converges), then a simple integration by parts shows that
$$
f(0^+)= \lim_{s \to +\infty} \, s \hat{f}(s),
$$
a result sometimes referred to (e.g. in Wikipedia) as the initial value theorem.

Now in probability for a non-negative random variable $T$, it is also standard to consider its Laplace transform, which is simply the expectation value:
$$
\hat{f}(s)= \mathbb{E} \left(e^{-s T} \right)
$$
Thereby all moments can be obtained by simple differentiation at $s=0$ (assuming sufficient differentiability; a lack of it signals some moments may not even exist because e.g. the distribution is heavy-tailed)

However there is a relationship I have read somewhere andthat I understand intuitively but  that I am unable to prove, which is
$$
\lim_{s \to 0} \hat{f}(s) = {\rm Proba}(T < +\infty)
$$
This should be helpful to detect if the distribution is defective, i.e. if it contains a Dirac delta peak at infinity...

Comment: Is it the limit $s\to 0^+$?

Comment: Yes. But since $\hat{f}(s)$ is analytic in $s$ that should not matter I think

Comment: Even if $T=+\infty$ almost surely for example?

Comment: Assuming the LT is at least locally analytic around the origin should suffice to exclude this pathological case ?